# MySQL select statement giving me trouble

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble with a MySQL query.

I have 3 tables: table1, table2 and table3.

What I want to do is get a distinct count of the codes from table1 where the date was in June 2013 and the it was of type "N" and where the status from table3 was never 'Confirmation'.

At the moment I am getting results that contain status of 'Confirmation' because there can be many status linked to a code. So I want to ensure that my result set never contained 'Confirmation'. Long winded, but I hope thorough.

Here is my query:

```
select count(distinct(code)) 
  from table1 
 where date between '2013-06-01' and '2013-07-01' 
   and type = 'N' 
   and id in (select id 
                from table2 
               where id_response in (select id_response 
                                       from table3 
                                      where status NOT LIKE 'Confirmation'));
```

I know my query is not ideally written, so I welcome all suggestions to help me make this better and get the results I need.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Perhaps showing some sample data and expected output would help.

Comment: What is the relationship between table1 and table3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will work :

```
select
table1.code, 
count(table1.code) 
from table1 
INNER JOIN table2 on (table1.id = table2.id)
where table1.date between '2013-06-01' and '2013-07-01' and table1.type = 'N' 
AND table2.id_response NOT IN 
(Select  table3.id_response from table3 WHERE table3.status = 'Confirmation')
GROUP BY table1.code
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, however this doesn't seem correct. Because there can be multiple status for a code, I need to ensure that each code NEVER had a status of 'Confirmation'. Your query seems to be including codes that at one point have had a status of 'Confirmation'

Comment: @StefanHanotin: Have updated my query, kindly check and let me know, if this works :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
select table1.code, count(table1.code) 
from table1, table2, table3
where table1.date between '2013-06-01' and '2013-07-01'
and table1.type = 'N'
and table1.id = table2.id
and table2.id_response = table3.id_response
and table3.status <> 'Confirmation'
GROUP BY table1.code
```